# how to search and update record mysql in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have problem to search and update record database sql.
this is my code. i using mysql database and Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf closeMsgbox)
    objconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=AAA;userid=root;password= 'root'")
    Dim username As Boolean = True
    objconn.Open()
    Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM daftar WHERE nid = '" & FormRegister.TextBox1.Text & "';"
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    command.Connection = objconn
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    data = command.ExecuteReader
    If data.HasRows() = True Then
        While data.Read()
            FormRegister.Show()
            tkhupd = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            command.Connection = objconn
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE visitor SET tkhupd  ='" & tkhupd & "' WHERE                      nokp = '" & FormRegister.TextBox1.Text & "';"
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("You're has logout")
            FormRegister.TextBox1.Text = ""
            username = False
            Me.Close()
        End While
    Else
        FormRegister.Show()
        username = True
    End If
    data.Close()
    If username = True Then
        Dim sqlquery2 As String = "INSERT INTO visitor (nid)VALUES ('" & FormRegister.TextBox1.Text & "')"
        Dim data2 As MySqlDataReader
        Dim adapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand
        command2.CommandText = sqlquery2
        command2.Connection = objconn
        adapter2.SelectCommand = command2
        data2 = command2.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("You're has login")
        Form4.Show()
        FormRegister.TextBox1.Text = ""
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

but i have error on Word command.ExecuteNonQuery(): MySqlException was unhandled. There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Comment: Your code will be vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a separate `MySqlCommand` object, say `command2` inside your `While` statement , because `command` is already in active use:

```
Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand
..
While data.Read()
    ..
    command2.Connection = objconn
    ..
End While
```

Comment: do you know how to save login & logout time in database using vb 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this all in one call to the database, comprising two statements. I'm more used to Sql Server, so this syntax may be a little off, but it would look something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sqlquery As String = _
         "DECLARE @RowCount Int;" & _
         " UPDATE FROM visitor v" & _
            " INNER JOIN daftar d ON d.nid = v.nokp" & _
            " SET v.tkhupd = current_timestamp" & _
            " WHERE d.nid = ?NID;" & _
         " SELECT row_count() INTO @RowCount;" & _
         " IF @RowCount = 0 THEN " & vbCrLf & _
            " INSERT INTO visitor (nid) VALUES (?NID);" & vbCrLf & _
         " END IF"

    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=AAA;userid=root;password= 'root'"), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("?NID", MySqlDbTypes.Int).Value = Integer.Parse(FormRegister.TextBox1.Text)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```